# HQL query causing insufficient disk space exception

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hql

I have following SQL query, which I translated to HQL:

```
SELECT f.date,
    f.name,
    SUM(f.seats) 
FROM Foo f 
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
                FROM Foo fh 
                WHERE f.start + f.end IN (  SELECT fl.start + fl.end 
                                                            FROM Foo fl 
                                                            WHERE fl.date BETWEEN dateadd(yy,-1,fh.date) 
                                                                AND fh.date 
                                                                AND fl.name = '<name>') 
                    AND f.date = fh.date 
                    AND fh.date >= '2016-01-01'
                    AND fh.name = '<name>' ) 
    AND f.date >= '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY f.date,
    f.name 
ORDER BY f.date ASC,
    SUM(f.seats) DESC
```

In my application this query causes the error in the title:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:4853)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1781)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1034)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:986)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
```

This is obviously cause by the sheer inefficiency of the query as well as the number of times its executed as well as the amount of rows it works with.

---

Lets explain what the query does. Following example:

I have data on uber drivers. Each row is one drive of the driver with date (month), driver name, seats the driver had available, start location and end location.

E. g.:

```
Date        Name    Seats       Start   End
-------------------------------------------
7/1/2019    John    45          A       B
```

The data is summed per month. So `John` had 9 drives between `A` and `B` and each time he had 5 seats available. Of course, there are also other people who drive the same route and therefore pose as competition to `John`.

```
Date        Name    Seats       Start   End
-------------------------------------------
7/1/2019    John    45          A       B
7/1/2019    Doe     25          A       A
7/1/2019    Alice   35          A       C
7/1/2019    John    30          A       A
7/1/2019    Doe     25          A       C
7/1/2019    Alice   10          A       B
7/1/2019    Doe     5           A       B
7/1/2019    Alice   15          A       A
```

So for `7/1/2019` `John`s "network" (all routes) had this competition:

```
Date        Name    Seats   Route
---------------------------------
7/1/2019    John    30      A-A
7/1/2019    Doe     25      A-A
7/1/2019    Alice   15      A-A

7/1/2019    John    45      A-B
7/1/2019    Doe     5       A-B
7/1/2019    Alice   10      A-B
```

As you can see, in this result, the route `A-C` is not listed, because `John` didn't drive it at all. If we expand the example data by a new month `8/1/2019`:

```
Date        Name    Seats       Start   End
-------------------------------------------
8/1/2019    John    65          A       C
8/1/2019    Doe     25          A       A
8/1/2019    Alice   35          A       A
8/1/2019    Doe     25          A       B
8/1/2019    Alice   10          A       B
8/1/2019    Doe     5           A       C
8/1/2019    Alice   15          A       C
```

we can see that `John` only drove `A-C` this month. As the `network` should be build over a timespan of 1 year into the past (8/1/2018 to 8/1/2019), `John`s network is now all three routes (`A-A`, `A-B`, `A-C`), but only for calculating the competitors as of `8/1/2019`. For `7/1/2019`, `John`s network stays `A-A`, `A-B`. So the result for `8/1/2019` is this:

```
Date        Name    Seats   Route
---------------------------------
8/1/2019    John    0       A-A
8/1/2019    Doe     25      A-A
8/1/2019    Alice   35      A-A

8/1/2019    John    0       A-B
8/1/2019    Doe     25      A-B
8/1/2019    Alice   10      A-B

8/1/2019    John    65      A-C
8/1/2019    Doe     5       A-C
8/1/2019    Alice   10      A-C
```

`John` only drove `A-C`, which is the reason, why he is counted with 0 seats for the other routes.

As the results are summing the seats and ignore the route, the actual output of the query is as following:

```
7/1/2019    John    75          <-- 30+45
7/1/2019    Doe     30          <-- 25+5
7/1/2019    Alice   25          <-- 10+15

8/1/2019    John    65          <-- 65+0+0
8/1/2019    Doe     55          <-- 25+25+5
8/1/2019    Alice   55          <-- 35+10+10
```

In this result we have as routes for `7/1/2019` only `A-A` and `A-B` for `John`s competitors, as there is no data before that date. For `8/1/2019` `John`s network is `A-A`, `A-B` and `A-C`, even though he only drove `A-C` in `8/1/2019` (`A-A` and `A-B` were in `7/1/2019`).

I hope the data I provided is understandable. If you need more clarification, just ask and I will try to explain even more.

---

**How do I need to change my query to greatly increase the performance?**

I have not used `JOIN`s so far, because I had to join on a subquery, and that is not allowed in HQL.

---

<sub>If you need more info/clarification, feel free to ask!</sub>

---

EDIT:

I know that I could have also posted on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I chose against it, because the query itself works, if only performed for 1 name and only fails for more. My understanding of `codereview.stackexchange.com` is, that there should only be performance improvement questions

Comment: I suggest you fix the examples such that the seats add up in order not to confuse readers of this question

Comment: Did you try the resulting SQL query directly in some SQL client and have it explained? If it would return a lot of data that would explain the memory issue but if it doesn't the database still could create a huge temporary table (which that error seems to indicate). So I'd first try to analyze and fix the SQL and then try to adjust the HQL query to make Hibernate generate the SQL I want.

Comment: ... in fact, I'm sure this could be quite "easy" to solve with window functions, but instead of fixing your existing query, I'd love to review your original requirements with a well-designed example and start from there. Pretty sure you can forget HQL (as I already suggested in your previous question) :)

Comment: @Thomas If I run that query for just 1 name, it returns less than 3k rows. So its not an issue with the amount of results, but with how the query gets processed by the database if ran multiple times (creates huge temporary table). I did post the SQL query instead of the HQL one, because its easier to fix SQL than HQL

Comment: @LukasEder I have updated the examples and they should add up now. As you have explained to me in my previous question, I thought I was able to eleminate all carthesian products from the query. I doubt that a computed column for `start + end` would solve the memory issue at hand. If you need more info or something is unclear, feel free to ask and I'll try to provide understandable explanations

Comment: I see, that `Foo` and `Bar` suggested it was HQL (which nowadays sometimes looks very much like SQL). If this already is SQL did you try and get the query plan? I don't know SQL server but Postgresql would support `EXPLAIN <query>` with a few options to help figure out where exactly the huge temp table is being created. However, I back Lukas' suggestion to try and tackle your original requirements which might be a lot easier.

Comment: As for your example: I'm still not sure I understand it. Could you provide a simpler example (like smaller number of seats) as well as one that fits your query (`start + end` indicates those are numbers ao `A, B, C` increases the confusion)? Additionally your statement "Doe and Alice are only in the results for 7/1/2019 and 8/1/2019" doesn't fit because they are both in the input and the output. Could you correct and expand that description of why the output should be the way you want it to be (describe the algorithm which works best with a simple example).

Comment: I really suggest you delete this question and start from scratch again. Your examples do not show your requirements at all. Your description contradicts your examples...

Comment: Its hard to describe the issue at hand, because I can't share what its actually about. I will try to make it more understandable. I thought the working query makes it understandable. Hell, I can't even think about a title wich would describe it shortly

Comment: See it as practice to solve problems :) I'm pretty sure, this is an instance of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). I'd really love to know what exactly you're trying to solve (i.e. X). I'm quite convinced that your Y is too far advanced for us to reverse engineer X from it.

Comment: I'll completely rework this question on monday. Though I might already have a solution which works. Still gonna rework it, so anyone can give a possible better solution

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Feel free to provide your solution as an answer here!

Comment: @LukasEder I have updated the example data. It should be way easier to understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this query shortly after posting the question:

```
SELECT f.date,
    f.name,
    SUM(f.seats) 
FROM Foo f 
WHERE f.start + f.end IN (  SELECT fh.start + fh.end 
                            FROM Foo fh 
                            WHERE fh.date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, f.date) 
                                AND f.date 
                                AND fh.name = '<name>') 
    AND f.date >= '2016-01-01' 
GROUP BY f.date,
    f.name 
ORDER BY f.date ASC,
    SUM(f.seats) DESC
```

As you can see, I pretty much just removed the `WHERE EXISTS` clause. I am not quite certain if that was the right thing to do, or what errors this could cause, but it at least solved the error at hand (insufficient disk space exception).

If you have another idea or remarks on my query, feel free to share them!

Comment: That query looks good. One suggestion: I wouldn't use concatenation of `start + end` to generate an itinerary type as there's a slight risk of ambiguity, e.g. when `start` values are `'A', 'AB'` and `end` values are `BC` and `C`. Either use a separator token between the values, which doesn't exist in the data set, or compare `f.start = fh.start` and `f.end = fh.end` separately, using `EXISTS()` rather than `IN`

Comment: I see what you mean with the "risk of ambiguity". I now switched to `EXISTS()` and it also seem to increase the fetching performance!

Comment: Think about my example. You have one row that has `start = 'A' and end = 'BC'`. Another row has `start = 'AB' and end = 'C'`. Those two rows have equal values of `start + end`. Probably not what you want.